# Addition of Fractions by Two Different Methods that Don't Agree?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

We can add fractions by mainly 2 methods (atleast I know only two).

1.LCD

2.LCM

I will add two different fractions by both the methods.

Fraction is:

1/36 + 1/27

By LCM

Dividing the denominator by 9.

We get,

1/4 + 1/3

Cross multiplying

3+4/ Lcm of 36 & 27

ie;

7/108.

Now By LCD

1×27/36×27 + 1×36/27×36

This gives,

63/972 = 7/108

Other Fraction is:

5/6+1/15

By LCM

Dividing denominator by 3

we get

5/2 + 1/5

Cross multiplying

25+2/ LCM of 6 & 15

ie;

27/90 = 0.3

By LCD

5×15/6×15 + 1×6/15×6

This will be

75+6/90= 81/90 = 0.9

Here in second fraction, I am getting two different answers.

Please, tell where I am going wrong. Is my method of solving by LCM in second fraction wrong?
This question seems to be childish, I know.Since I don't have any mentor to ask I am compelled to ask here. But please help! I am still learning.

Thank you

Comment: This is very hard to follow, it's never clear which expressions are meant to equal which other expressions...you just write one after the other with no explanation.  In any case, $\frac 56=\frac {25}{30}$ and $\frac 1{15}=\frac 2{30}$ so $\frac 56+\frac 1{15}=\frac {27}{30}=\frac 9{10}$.

Comment: Just guessing, but I think the error for the "other fraction" comes when you appear to declare that LCM$(6,15)=90$.  This is not true, that LCM is $30$.  As I say, though, it is hard to follow what you wrote so I'm not sure I have it right.

Comment: @lulu Yes your correct. The Lcm is 30 & not 90. Thank u very much.

Answer (score 1):

> 1/4 + 1/3
>
> Cross multiplying
>
> 3+4/ Lcm of 36 & 27
>
> ie;
>
> 7/108

This is not correct. Note that 1/4 and 1/3 are *each* way bigger than 7/108.